# Rename a view in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, configuration-management

Is it possible to rename a clearcase view ? If yes how to do it.

I usually give view name based on fix or enhancements that I would make in that view. Once complete I end up reusing that view for some other task. With other SCMs I do not have any problem, I understand based on its changes to the build tree. The clearcase very slow, if I have to know by change set it will take me 2-5 mins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a snapshot view, you can rename the root directory safely.

But for any view, (snapshot or dynamic), check [`cleartool mkview -view -replace`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktag.htm). It should allow you to *replace* a tag, effectively renaming your view.

Make sure your view is stopped first (`cleartool endview -server yourView`)

```
-rep/lace
```

> Replaces an existing tag registry entry with a new entry. (No error occurs if the tag does not exist.)
>   You can use this option to change the tag comment and access paths.
>   **You cannot use `-replace` to change an existing tag's name; to do this, delete the tag with `rmtag` and then use `mktag`**.

The last part actually points out the need to remove and then recreate the tag associated to your view.

Make sure to `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro yourView` first, in order to get all the parameters you will need when recreating the tag with the new name.

Answer (score 2):

For a dynamic view, you can use the following:

```
cleartool mktag -view -replace -tag <new view name> -host <Server host> \
-gpath <Global path> <Global path>
```

Where `Server host` and `Global path` can be obtained from the output of

```
cleartool lsview -l <view name to be renamed>
```

Then you remove the tag of the renamed view (`old view name`) via

```
cleartool rmtag -view <old view name>
```

Comment: Why do we need two `<Global Path>`s?